# Gstreamer. Undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle'

Tags: c, qt, qt5, gstreamer

I am trying to use gstreamer and Qt5 together. Just the simple app with src->sink - for displaying something on the screen.

Here is an example of source code:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/videooverlay.h>    

...

WId xwinid = window.winId();
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle( (GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (sink)), xwinid);
```

And here I have got the next errors:

```
/.../gst_qt/main.cpp:33: error: undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle'
/.../gst_qt/main.cpp:33: error: undefined reference to `gst_video_overlay_get_type'
```

I found the both .c and .h "videooverlay" files in my environment, but it looks weird, that header cannot call the sources.

In my .pro file I have included gstreamer:

```
# files needed for gstreamer
INCLUDEPATH += /.../usr/include/gstreamer-1.0
INCLUDEPATH += /.../usr/include/glib-2.0
INCLUDEPATH += /.../usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
INCLUDEPATH += /.../usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0

# external libraries
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-1.0
PKGCONFIG += gobject-2.0
PKGCONFIG += glib-2.0
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: Undefined references typically mean it found the header but not the lib. Maybe you need something additional, like this: `PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-video-1.0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to add the video library portion of GStreamer since you use symbols that are only defined in there:

```
PKGCONFIG += gstreamer-video-1.0
```

EDIT: credits go to @JarMan, he was faster.. just made a comment instead of an answer for some reason :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! A question remains on my side : is there an easy way to know which libraries portion to link against to use a given feature of gstreamer ? Preferably from docs, or a naming convention ?

Comment: Note on my previous comment, as I found the answer and maybe it could interest some other people x) Actually in the gstreamer lib documentation, the side treeview of API references gives an idea of what library to link against : the page of a given feature is part of the tree of its library. I also assume names in each lib are like GstThelibThefunction or gst_thelib_thefunction.